# SQL Query to get and update today and yesterday's data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Alright, I have to create a similar table structure  to mine more simplified -

```
Test_Table: EmployeeId,Points,Date
Test_Table1:Score,EmployeeId,Date
Leaderboards_Table: Points,Score,EmployeeId,Day,Month,Year
```

Now I need to write a single query to update or insert into LeaderBoards_Table something like -

```
UPDATE Leaderboards_Table
      SET Points=pts,Score=total_score
FROM
    (
      (SELECT 
           (SELECT SCORE from  Test_Table1 WHERE Employee = @EmployeeId AND DAY(DATE)=10       AND  MONTH(DATE)=12 AND YEAR(DATE)=2010) as pts

    )
    Points as pts
   from Test_Table where  Employee = @EmployeeId AND DAY(DATE)=10 AND MONTH(DATE)=12 AND      YEAR(DATE)=2010
  )
WHERE EmployeeId=@EmployeeId and DAY=10 AND MONTH=12 AND YEAR=2010
```

Now the above query only updates for today...what I want to do is also update yesterday 
also in a single query I dont want to write another query....so is there anyway to do a single query to update yesterday and today's points.

**UPDATE**: Also this query will be called lot of times..so it would be great to have the most performance effective query for this.

Answer (score 1):

Its a lot easier if you change to joins instead of subqueries.

```
UPDATE Leaderboards_Table
SET 
     Points=t1.score,
     Score=total_score
FROM
   Leaderboards_Table lt 
   INNER JOIN Test_Table1 t1
   ON lt.employee_ID = t1.employee_id 
   INNER JOIN Test_Table t
   ON lt.employee_ID = t1.employee_id 
      and lt.date = t1.date  
WHERE
 EmployeeId=@EmployeeId and DAY IN (9,10) AND MONTH=12 AND YEAR=2010
```

Comment: So just a question..this query is going to be called quite a few times..is doing a join not slower compared to subqueries ?

Comment: Also leaderboards table does not have a date column in it..so cant join on that..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses the BETWEEEN clause.

```
UPDATE Leaderboards_Table
SET Points=tt.Points, Score = tt1.Score
FROM LeaderBoards_Table
JOIN Test_Table1 tt1 ON LeaderBoards_Table.EmployeeId = tt1.EmployeeId
JOIN Test_Table tt ON tt1.EmployeeId = tt.EmployeeId
WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
    AND CONVERT(datetime CAST(YEAR AS varchar) + CAST(MONTH AS varchar) + CAST(DAY AS varchar))
            BETWEEN '20101209' AND '20101210'
```